# Trying to understand searching through a nested dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of contact information stored in a nested `dict`:

```
addressBook = {'Jim': {'name': 'James Marsh', 'address': '32 Morris Ave',
                           'phone': '654-987-3217'},
    'Leanne': {'name': 'Leanne Moss', 'address': '37 Shamrock Lane',
                           'phone': '123-456-7890'},
    'Chris': {'name': 'Christopher Philips', 'address': '49 Langley Court',
                           'phone': '321-654-9870'},
'Tim': {'name': 'Timothy Morris', 'address': '49 Langley Court',
                       'phone': '321-654-9870'}}
```

and I'm trying to write a function which will search through each entry for a user-entered search string.

```
def searchAllFields(addressBook):
    searchString = input("Enter a string to search for (enter to cancel): ")
    if searchString == "":
        return
    else:
        for key, value in addressBook.items():
            inside = False
            for v in value.values():
                if searchString in v:
                    inside = True
                    break
            if searchString in key or inside:
                print("The following contacts were found: ")
                print(addressBook[key]['name'])
                print(addressBook[key]['address'])
                print(addressBook[key]['phone'] + '\n')
            else:
                print("No contact matching the string {} was found.".format(searchString))
                return
```

My function iterates through the dictionary nicely, but it only finds the search string in the keys. For example, if my search string in `Jim`, I can find James' information, but if my search string is `Lang` I want to be able to find Chris. I would have thought that `for key, value in addressBook.items():` would look through the values as well as the keys. Why doesn't it? How could I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `searchString in value` you're only checking the keys of that `value` dictionary.

You would need a second loop to check against the values of the nested dictionary

```
for key, value in addressBook.items():
    inside = False
    for v in value.values():
        if searchString in v:
            inside = True 
            break
    if searchString in key or inside:
```

Unrelated note: `searchString in key` is checking substrings, not an exact match

Comment: I added an `elif` block to search through the values, but it gives the same results.

Comment: Again, `in dict` will only search the keys of that `dict`

Answer (score 1):

You need to test whether an input is a substring of *either* keys *or* values of values within your nested dictionary.

If partial matches are acceptable, you can achieve this by using `any` with a generator expression:

```
for key, value in addressBook.items():
    if (searchString in key) or any(searchString in i for i in value.values()):
        print(...)
```

---

A variation on this is to utilise `collections.namedtuple`, which makes more sense for structured data. This does involve a one-off transformation cost.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Contact = namedtuple('Contact', ['name', 'address', 'phone'])
d = {k: Contact(**v) for k, v in addressBook.items()}

for key, value in d.items():
    if (searchString in key) or any(searchString in i for i in value):
        print(...)
```